# How to Convert from unsigned char* to array<unsigned char>^?

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, c++-cli

How do I convert an array of unsigned chars to

```
 array<unsigned char>^ ?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this boost::array<> ?

Comment: mind the `^`: this a .NET array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create a managed array, and copy the data. Simple.

```
array<Byte>^ MakeManagedArray(unsigned char* input, int len)
{
    array<Byte>^ result = gcnew array<Byte>(len);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        result[i] = input[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Yes, I'm sure there's a way to use the Marshal class to do the copy for you, or to get a pointer to the managed array you can pass to `memcpy`, but this works, and it doesn't require research on MSDN to verify that it's correct.

Comment: Agreed.  But make it array<Byte>^.

Comment: D'oh. That's what I get for not checking myself with the compiler.

Comment: @Hans : I've seen you make that "correction" a few times -- what's the rationale? Do you advocate `Int32` over `int` as well? (I'd use `unsigned char` over `Byte` here, personally.)

Comment: I like Byte here as well, because `array<Byte>^` is a managed type, and in C# it would be `byte[]`. Since `char` is something different in C#, I prefer `Byte` when part of a managed object.

Comment: @ildjarn - I don't.  Eradicating the notion that characters and bytes are interchangeable is a long battle with small victories.